# react native scrollTo using ref with hooks inside setInterval

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, setinterval, ref

I am working on this component and couldn't find a way to get the `scrollViewRef` to work inside `setInterval`. I have tried using `scrollViewRef` and `scrollViewRef.current` both but gives undefined is not an object. I believe as modal is visible after `onpress` so `scrollViewRef` is not updated inside `setInterval`.

```
   const App = () => {
    let interval;
    let scrollViewRef = useRef(null);
    const imageRef = useRef(null);
    const [x, setX] = useState(1);
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
    const [top, setTop] = useState('#87cefa');
    const [left, setLeft] = useState('#cdcdcd');
    const [right, setRight] = useState('#cdcdcd');
    const [bottom, setBottom] = useState('#cdcdcd');
    const [imageSize, setImageSize] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        // console.log(scrollViewRef);
        Image.getSize(
            'https://jjj.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1/out8.jpeg',
            (width, height) => {
                setImageSize({
                    imageWidth: width,
                    imageHeignt: height,
                    quadrantSize: Math.round(width / 4),
                });
            }
        );
    }, []);

    const onBackPress = () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
        // SoundPlayer.stop();
        setModalVisible(false);
        setX(1);
        setTop('#87cefa');
        setLeft('#cdcdcd');
    };

    const onPress = () => {
        setModalVisible(true);
        // SoundPlayer.playSoundFile('aaa', 'mp3');

        interval = setInterval(() => {
            scroll(x);
        }, 50);
    };

    const scroll = (x) => {
        const quadrantSize2 = imageSize.quadrantSize * 2;
        const quadrantSize3 = imageSize.quadrantSize * 3;
        const quadrantSize4 = imageSize.quadrantSize * 4;
        // countRef.current.scrollTo({ x: 8, animated: true });
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('uhuihiuh');
            scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ x: 8, animated: true });
        }, 50);
        if (x === imageSize.imageWidth) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            setTimeout(() => {
                onBackPress();
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            setX(x + 1);
        }
        if (x <= imageSize.quadrantSize && x >= 1) {
            setTop('#87cefa');
            setLeft('#cdcdcd');
        } else if (x >= imageSize.quadrantSize && x <= quadrantSize2) {
            setRight('#87cefa');
            setTop('#cdcdcd');
        } else if (x >= quadrantSize2 && x <= quadrantSize3) {
            setBottom('#87cefa');
            setRight('#cdcdcd');
        } else if (x >= quadrantSize3 && x <= quadrantSize4) {
            setLeft('#87cefa');
            setBottom('#cdcdcd');
        }
    };

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => onPress()}
                style={{
                    ...
                }}
            >
                <View
                    style={{
                        ...
                    }}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Image
                ref={imageRef}
                style={{
                    width: imageSize.imageWidth,
                    height: imageSize.imageHeignt,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    marginTop: 20,
                }}
                source={{
                    uri:
                        'https://jjj.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1/out8.jpeg',
                }}
                resizeMode="cover"
            />
            <Modal
                animationType="none"
                transparent={true}
                visible={modalVisible}
                onRequestClose={() => {
                    console.log('aaa');
                }}
            >
                <View style={{ ...styles.centeredView, borderWidth: 1 }}>
                    <View style={styles.modalView}>
                        <ScrollView
                            scrollToOverflowEnabled={true}
                            horizontal={true}
                            ref={scrollViewRef}
                        >
                            <Image
                                style={{
                                    height: imageSize.imageHeignt,
                                    width: 1550,
                                }}
                                source={{
                                    uri:
                                        'https://jjj.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1/out8.jpeg',
                                }}
                            />
                        </ScrollView>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
    };

    export default App;
```

I also tried understanding this:
https://upmostly.com/tutorials/settimeout-in-react-components-using-hooks

Comment: `scrollViewRef` can't be undefined, only `scrollViewRef.current` can be null. I suspect here that your Modal does not render its children (and therefore the scrollViewRef related component) until its shown so `scrollViewRef.current` is null. Second thing, `interval` variable is lost between render so you may want to use `useRef` for this too. If you want to simplify this behavior: create a component for you modal children and move your logic (hooks) for scrollView there, it should be easier to manage as you will not need to rely on `setTimeout`.

Comment: I am currently managing it using class based child component but would like to know how to do it using hooks.